# what if I need to go back to Raspbian repository?

Tags: repository

This site advertises access to more resources
https://raspberry-hosting.com/en/faq/free-raspbian-repository

I like to try that, but cannot find nowhere how to restore Raspbian BACK to to the original .

Comment: All motherly advises aside - I am asking how to restore / change current repository directive. Can you point me to some documentation , please.

Comment: Successfully copied SD to USB flash drive. Would like to make sure I can copy it  back from USB to SD. Asking Mrs Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an unknown repository is a major security risk. There have been several recent cases where the software was corrupted at the repository level.

Second, the safest way would be to back up your SD card first so that if needed you could revert, or even better use a new card with the new repository so that if the worst does happen you can limit the scope of any damage.